# SVN for perl project

Tags: java, perl, svn, netbeans, visualsvn-server

I managed to configure SVN for my java project. I used **VisualSVN Server** as server and I used **Netbeans** as client. I managed to connect to SVN server using Netbeans plugins. How do i create SVN for perl projects as I know there is no IDE for perl. We need to use perl editor (texteditor,notepad++ and so on) for coding. In this case how do I configure the client for perl project so I can do commit, update or checkout as like in Netbeans. Please advice.

Comment: While it is your choice, I suggest you to use Git. It's easier to use and more stable (SVN tends to fail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are running windows PC then you should download and install tortoise SVN. it will allow you to check in check out and manage repository.

if you are running with Linux machine so for that you need to install `KDESVN`

Comment: tortoise svn.. you have to commit and update manually.. like right click the file in explorer and commit.. do we have IDE for perl..like Netbeans and Eclipse for java.

Comment: http://padre.perlide.org/ check this may be it will helpful dont know svn support is there or not

Answer (score 0):

Since you like NetBeans, you might wanna try this http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36183/perl-on-netbeans